# how to color a dataframe full of strings with seaborn?

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn

I would like each fluid to have a different color and then be able to pass the matrix to png

[Dataframe full of strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UqEo.png)

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 5))
sns.heatmap(fluidos_frame, annot=True, linewidths=.5, 
ax=ax,cmap = 'viridis')


plt.xlabel('Th[K]')
plt.ylabel('m[kg/s]')
plt.savefig(path + 'Matrix_r124_MW.png')
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'R134a'

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i tried with seaborn heatmat but giveme a error with the strings

Comment: Please edit your question and post your best coding attempt, the input data as text (don't post data/code/error messages as images), and the full traceback of your error message.